# Jquery Detect from span and append to td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a number of rows in a table that are formatted a bit like this...

```
<td class="inline-entity-form-node-field_rate_dates">
<div class="field field-name-field-rate-dates field-type-datetime field-label-hidden">
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">
<span class="date-display-start" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2015-09-28T00:00:00-04:00">
Monday, September 28, 2015
</span> to 
<span class="date-display-end" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2015-09-30T00:00:00-04:00">
Wednesday, September 30, 2015
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

What I'd like to do is grab the value from "content" in span class "date-display-start" (in this case, content="2015-09-28T00:00:00-04:00") and append it to the TD...so that it would be come:

td data-order="2015-09-28T00:00:00-04:00"

and iterate through every row that way...

I'm more of a PHP/Backend person - so any help in the jQuery would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
$(function(){
    // Find spans with class date-display-start and iterate over each
    $('span.date-display-start').each(function(){
        // closest finds the closest element matching the selector traversing up through its ancestors.
        // Here we find the closest td and set its attribute for data-order = the the current span's content
        $(this).closest('td').attr('data-order', $(this).attr('content'));
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w4t6qgk/)